# How to start a build via a phrase in Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am switching from the github pull request builder plugin (for security reasons) and am trying to get the same functionality from Pipelines (using different plugin). I think I have just about everything, however I can't seem to find a way to re-trigger a build simply by a trigger phrase like in github pull request builder plugin. Is that possible via pipelines?

By trigger phrase, I mean that a user can make a comment on the PR saying "Jenkins re-test" and it will kick off the build again.

Comment: What do you mean by "a trigger phrase"? Do you mean something like [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/5244/11820)?

Comment: @biruk1230 No, I just added a bit more info - let me know if that explains it better

Comment: Your question sounds like you're trying to switch from the freestyle job "github pull request builder" functionality to a pipeline functionality using the same plugin ("find a way to re-trigger a build simply by a trigger phrase."). I think that you need specify that you don't wand to use 'ghprb' plugin at all and trying to find another plugin which can be used in pipelines.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this @JustinPihony?  I'm trying to do something just like this.  I want to use pipelines without ghprb plugin and not run the tests (it can do everything else in my pipeline) until I make a comment on the PR saying "test this please".

Comment: @JulieMarie No - I ended up bailing on pipelines altogether...

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition at the top of the build script to check for the message. You can access the changesets using `currentBuild.ChangeSets`. The last changeset is at the end of the array. Then you need to access the last element of that changeset. Finally you can access the message via `message` property. You can then search for your keyword.

I am doing the opposite (not triggering the build with a phrase) but never tried for pullrequests though.

Another idea is to use the "ignore builds with specific message" property and setting this message to be a regex with look ahead that accepts everything except the keyword. I don't really recall the syntax though :/